# Porque razão os madeirenses chamam cubanos aos continentais?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica

Porque razão os madeirenses chamam cubanos aos continentais?

Qual a origem desta expressão, neste contexto?

Comment: Excelente pergunta!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredita-se que a origem da expressão remota ao 25 de abril de 1974, em que a revolução dos cravos, protagonizada pela ["classe operária, os trabalhadores, as massas populares e os militares progressistas – «os capitães de Abril» –, unidos na aliança Povo-MFA, com o papel determinante do PCP"](http://www.pcp.pt/45o-aniversario-da-revolucao-de-abril-valores-de-abril-no-futuro-de-portugal), derrotou a ditadura do Estado Novo.

Nessa altura, os "ilhéus" (termo que os habitantes do continente utilizavam para se referirem aos habitantes dos arquipélagos) passaram a chamar "cubanos" aos habitantes do continente, o que pode ter servido para criticar o novo rumo político do país (influência do comunismo), ainda que possam ser [listados vários motivos.](http://aprenderamadeira.net/gentilicos-e-alcunhas-coletivas/)